# Decorator/wrapper: How to deal with arguments after positional/keyword args are all assigned to wrapped function's parameters?

Tags: python, arguments, wrapper, decorator

I'm wondering if there's a way in Python for a wrapper to get access to a function's arguments after they've already been resolved into parameters. So for instance, I'd like to wrap two functions that have different (numbers of) parameters:

```
def fn_1(a, b=None, config=None):
    ...

def fn_2(b=None, config=None):
    ...
```

I'd *like* for my wrapper to see if `config` has a value and, if not, to load it from somewhere else:

```
class with_config(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
       self.f = f
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       if config not in kwargs:
           kwargs[config] = load_config_from_some_default_location()
```

but I don't know how to determine if `config` has been passed positionally, as its position in the `args` list can vary from function to function.

If I could get ahold of the arguments **after** the positional ones have been given names according to the parameters (e.g. first positional assigned to `a`, second to `b`, third to `config`) I'd be A-OK.

The situation is slightly more complex than this but I think this gets my question across.

Any tips?

Comment: I don't know how I missed [this similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/830937/python-convert-args-to-kwargs?rq=1) but I'm guessing that's the best I'll do. Anyone with more ideas feel free to chime in.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
import inspect

def func(a, b=None, config=None):
    args, _, _, values = inspect.getargvalues(inspect.currentframe())
    print args # prints 'a', 'b', 'config'
    print values # prints {'a':12, 'b':None, 'config':None}
    if values['config'] == None:
        # Load config from somewhere else

if __name__ == '__main__':
    func(12)
```

Comment: This does work well in the case you show! In the wrapper case I don't think it will work because the args for that frame are those that were passed to the wrapper, not to the original. I'd be interested to see if this worked by analyzing another frame or something though? I need to review the inspect docs

Comment: Aha! If we use `inspect.getargspec(self.f)[0]` to get the `ArgSpec`, as you do here, and then zip these up with the `args` list as passed to `__call__` then everything's gravy

Answer (score 0):

I finally went with [this solution from Nadia Alramli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/831164/1256058):

`class with_config(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
       self.f = f
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       kwargs.update(dict(zip(self.f.func_code.co_varnames, args)))
       if config not in kwargs:
           kwargs[config] = load_config_from_some_default_location()
       return self.f(**kwargs)`